# Crypting Passwords in database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a fully populated PostgerSQL database, and a Java JEE project (JSF) that I have to migrate to a spring boot application.

 You see migrating the fonctionalities of the application isn't really a problem as well as keeping the records in the database is possible as it'is fully managed with JPA. 
 
But I am using [the latest spring security tool suit][1] to manage authentification, and  since it's a really old project the passwords in the users table are not crypted, so connecting with an old account that allready exists in the database isn't possible since the passwords are not crypted.
I was wondering if there was a way to encrypt the passwords elegantly without doing it manually .(via ~40 PUT methods / a comand line runner bean e.g) 
Any suggestion - article -refrence - code exemple would be welcome. 
 
Thank you

Comment: Surely your 40 PUTs don't need to typed by hand, do they?

Comment: No they don't have to, it did not seem right to me, i was thinking mabe ther's another way ?